# SqlReader object does not read

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using `SqlReader` object(`reader`) to assign a string value from Sql-server database to an image's `ImageUrl`, but the `ImageUrl` is always empty while the `reader` object doesn't satisfy the `while` loop condition when debugging.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "select profilePicture from Users where username = '@username'";
        command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Identity.Name;
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ProfilePhotoButton.ImageUrl = reader[0].ToString();
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have single quotes enclosing your parameter. Remove that.

```
 string query = "select profilePicture from Users where username = '@username'";
                                                                  //HERE
```

It should be:

```
 string query = "select profilePicture from Users where username = @username";
```

Enclosing value in single quotes would be take care by the parameter type you have specified while adding parameters to your command.

As a side note, enclose your Command and Connection object in `using` statement as well to ensure disposal of resources.